# Using Spring Data JPA specification to fetch projection interfaces

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am interested in Spring Data JPA [projection](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) but I need to use JPA [specification](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/). Is it possible to fetch projection interfaces with JPA specification?

Comment: so, what does happen when you try it?

Comment: You just simply extend JpaSpecificationExecutor in your repository interface and use your Projection definition as a return Type in the interface.

Comment: Any code what you have tried?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, this simply dooes not work and is **not supposed to work**, at least not for now https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1189

Answer (score 1):

A Spring-Data-JPA Enthusiast has created a project that implements projections with specifications. I am using it in my own project without problem. You may check it from here:

https://github.com/pramoth/specification-with-projection

**Update for database level projections**

There is an outdated comment below.

> Is not query optimized. It just map the results after they have been queried

The last version of this library supports database level projections [link to the commit](https://github.com/pramoth/specification-with-projection/commit/434d16b619fbdde56ecb952a656badd1ea0b1614#diff-efd5512421dc46456e0244f9fd478c90110265b95959c5e643010802ac4e1385R140).

**Update for the last Spring Boot versions**

Until [this pull request](https://github.com/pramoth/specification-with-projection/pull/22) is not merged, to support the last Spring Boot versions, fixed library sources can be copy pasted directly to the project from here
https://github.com/v-ladynev/specification-with-projection-embeded

Comment: @anat0lius It is optimized for now.